# JPQL query returns NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

I have following JPQL Query in my repository interface:

```
@Override
@Query(value = "SELECT mainFoo FROM MainFooEntity mainFoo JOIN FETCH mainFoo.nestedFoo.bar b WHERE b.value LIKE %:searchedFoo%")
Page<MainFooEntity> findByFoo(@Param("searchedFoo") String searchedFoo, Pageable pageable);
```

And here is my MainFooEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class MainFooEntity {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   private Long id;

   @Embedded
   private NestedFooEntity nestedFoo;

   // ...
}
```

NestedFooEntity class which is embeddable:

```
@Embeddable
public class NestedFooEntity {

    @Type(type = "com.my.BarType")
    @Column(name = "bar")
    private BarType bar;

    // ...
}
```

and my custom BarType class:

```
@lombok.Value
public class BarType implements Comparable<BarType>{
    String value;

    public BarType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

When I call repository method above I got following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.my.FooRepository.findByFoo(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:139)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:565)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:558)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:560)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:323)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:293)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3931)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3717)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3595)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy190.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
    ... 84 more
```

Do you have idea please what I did wrong? Thanks in advice for answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate throws NullPointerException from HqlSqlWalker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015261/hibernate-throws-nullpointerexception-from-hqlsqlwalker)

Answer (score 0):

Your Join Fetch clause isn't legal according to the JPA 2.1 specification (emphasis mine):

> The association referenced by the right side of the FETCH JOIN clause must be an association or element collection that is referenced from an entity or embeddable that is returned as a result of the query. **It is not permitted to specify an identification variable for the objects referenced by the right side of the FETCH JOIN clause, and hence references to the implicitly fetched entities or elements cannot appear elsewhere in the query**.

Therefore you need to change the query to this:

```
SELECT mainFoo 
FROM MainFooEntity mainFoo 
JOIN FETCH mainFoo.nestedFoo.bar 
WHERE mainFoo.nestedFoo.bar.value LIKE %:searchedFoo%
```

You might also consider raising an issue with Hibernate to improve the error message since throwing NPEs around is kinda rude, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that one of the classes on the path (`NestedFooEntity`) **is not an entity**, it is an embeddable object. So, it cannot be joined.

So, you can try it:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT mainFoo FROM MainFooEntity mainFoo 
    JOIN FETCH mainFoo.bar
    JOIN mainFoo.bar bar
    JOIN bar.b b 
    WHERE b.value LIKE %:searchedFoo% ")
```